# How should I make my button disappear and show the calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function subtraction(x,y) {
        var sub = (x/y);
        console.log("The answer is " +sub);
       return sub;
        
    }
```

```html
<button id="first" onclick="subtraction(50,10)">50/10</button><br>
        <button id="second">20+20</button><br>
        <button id="third">100-90</button>
```

Hey guys , currently I am learning functions, and I've been trying to make it with onclick event. But I can't seem to get it no matter how much I change the function . The button keeps staying after clicking instead of showing me the answer of the function . Could anyone tell me how to do it?  In the console it seems to work but I can't make the button disappear after clicking and show the text. Cheers.

If my explanation wasn't very clear. Here's a pic of what I'm trying to achieve :

https://prnt.sc/kp7qns

Comment: What have you tried to do in order to make the button disappear and display the message there?

Comment: At the moment, your function is just returning the resultng value, but it returning to nowhere, you should add it to an element, using `getElementById(...).textContent = sub` for example. Also, to make the button disappear, pass in `this` as the third parameter to the function, then in the function set the button `outerHTML` to nothing `""`

Answer (score 1):

How about having an answer `<div>` that you assign the result to?

I also renamed `subtraction` to `division` as that's its purpose.

```js
let first_but = document.getElementById('first');
let answer_div = document.getElementById('answer_div');
function division(x, y) {
        //calculate the result
        let result = x / y;
        //assign the result to the answer div
        answer_div.innerText = 'The answer is: ' + result.toString();
        //make the button "dissapear"
        first_but.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<button id="first" onclick="division(50, 10)">50/10</button><br>
<div id='answer_div'></div>
<button id="second">20+20</button><br>
<button id="third">100-90</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns nothing to the front end (except in the console). You need to return it into an element that you create in the function to replace the button.

Something like this:

```js
function subtraction(x,y) {
var sub = (x/y);
console.log("The answer is " +sub);

let button = document.getElementById('first'),
 result = document.createElement('span');

result.innerHTML = sub;
button.parentNode.replaceChild(result, button);

        
}
```

```html
<button id="first" onclick="subtraction(50,10)">50/10</button><br>
        <button id="second">20+20</button><br>
        <button id="third">100-90</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused Division with Subtraction, so I fixed it for you and added 2 other function so that it shows you the answer in Console then hides each button after being clicked.

```js
function division(x,y) {
    var sub = (x/y);
    console.log("The answer is " +sub);
    var x = document.getElementById("first")
    x.style.display="none";
    return sub;
 }
 
 function addition(x,y) {
    var sub = (x+y);
    console.log("The answer is " +sub);
    var x = document.getElementById("second")
    x.style.display="none";
    return sub;
 }
 
 function subtraction(x,y) {
    var sub = (x-y);
    console.log("The answer is " +sub);
    var x = document.getElementById("third")
    x.style.display="none";
    return sub;
 }
```

```html
<button id="first" onclick="division(50,10)">50/10</button><br>
<button id="second"onclick="addition(20,20)">20+20</button><br>
<button id="third" onclick="subtraction(100,90)">100-90</button>
```